# Jenkins downloading in advance dependencies in maven dependencyManagement section

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have the following maven structure in a multi-module project:

```
aggregator-level-0
-- module-level-1 (jar)
-- aggregator-level-1
---- module-level-2.1 (jar)
---- module-level-2.2 (jar)
```

The aggregator-level-0 pom is not only an aggregator but also the parent (inheritance) for the rest of the modules. It includes a DependencyManagement section.

The module-level-1 includes the module-level-2.1 as a runtime dependency, so I have added module-level-2.1 in the DependencyManagement section of the aggregator-level-0 pom.

When I build the project locally (maven 3.0.4), using the -o option and having my m2 local repository empty, everything works like a charm. Maven resolves perfectly the order to build the modules and deploys the artifacts well.

When I do the same in "jenkins" the build fails. It tries to get the module-level-2.1 when the dependency Management section in the parent pom is parsed, and of course it fails because it is not created/published yet.

Is this the expected behavior?
Do Maven and Jenkins get the dependencies at a different time?
Is it a bad practice to put in the dependency management section of a pom artifacts which will be built in a sub-module inheriting from that pom?